# lower case from a text file

Tags: python, file-io

I Have a file and am trying to convert words in lower case. This is what I have so far

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       lines = fileinput.lower()

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 7):

You are lowercasing the file object, not the line.

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       line = line.lower()
```

would work better..

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
lines = fileinput.lower()
```

Put this:

```
line = line.lower()
```

Full code:

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
    for line in fileinput:
        line = line.lower()
```

## This would work without error.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one line code for this purpose

```
file = open('example.txt', 'rt').read().lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       line = line.lower()
       #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
   for line in fileinput:
       line = line.rstrip().upper()
       print line
```

Comment: if newline `\n` characters after each line double up, then you will get double-spaced lines. added `.rstrip()` to remove any extra newline characters.